# "How to fix 'adjusting my max height' in class"

Tags: c++

I have to create a class called Heli which i have already done, but the problem is i don't know how to adjust my max height when i add a load to my helicopter.

So the thing is i tried a different ways to handle the problem but nothing worked. My last try was to define my add_load function as void and compare if load is zero and when it isnt't then redefine my max load, but i don't know how to call to my already set max heigth

header:

public:

```
Heli() :
    _x(0),
    _y(0),
    _z(0),
    max_height(0),
    min_height(0),
    max_load(0),
    _load(0)
{
}
```

...

```
void Add_Load(int load);

void Remove_Load(int load);
```

cpp file:
...

```
void Heli::Add_Load(int load) {
    _load += load;

    if(_load != 0)
    {
        max_height = (max_height / (_load*10));
    }
 }
```

...

main file:

```
int main()
{

    Heli a(100,-10,0,6000,0,300,0);  // x,y,z-Position, max./min. Flightheight; max. Load, load

    cout << "helicopter: " << a << endl << endl;

    a.Add_Load(100);
    cout << a << endl;

 }
```

Comment: ok thank you very much user3152801. i works now but i get the error  "warning comparing floating point with == or != is unsafe"

Comment: You should compare floating numbers like this:
if (std::abs(_load) >
std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()) instead of if (_load != 0.0f). 
I assumed that _load is a float. Also, you should initialize your floats with 0.0f and doubles with 0.0, not with 0.

Comment: thanks for the respond i solved it now by declaring an epsilon and compare the absolute amount of my _load minus zero and it works fine

Comment: I hope you defined the epsilon as well :) (google C++ declare vs define)

Comment: Sometimes you can fix this by just requiring integers or rounding internally. You can use a smaller measurement internally to get enough precision on an integer value (like grams instead of kilograms).

Comment: @MFnx :) yes i defined it as well.                                                                                by the way thanks for the help i already have finished my programm now